# How to convert a microphone with 4 pole TRRS to 3 pole TRS?

Tags: audio, adapter

I have bought a mic online which is 4 pole(TRRS) and would like to convert it to a 3 pole(TRS) as a 4 pole mic doesn't work with a pc. I have a 3 pole 3.5mm jack but I'd very much like to know the wiring to connect TRRS wires with a TRS jack, so that I can use it on my pc which has separate TRS AUDIO and TRS MIC.

Link to the mic I bought: https://www.amazon.in/gp/product/B01FY20V7A/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

Comment: "Product Is Not Compatible With A DSLR And Will Work Only With TRRS Jack Input" - so you know the name of the connector, next step is finding out what typical pinouts for TRS (tip ring sleeve. the 3 pole connector) and TRRS plugs on microphones are.

Comment: Just search “trrs to trs”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: 4 pole to 3 pole converter]4 pole(TRRS) to 3 pole(TRS) diagram

Answer (score 1):

You will need to purchase a TRRS to TRS adapter. They are readily available from several suppliers.